# Undefined reference when accessing a object hash

Tags: perl

I have this subroutine that gets an object on call from the surrounding system (in this case IRSSI-Proxy):

```
sub my_method {
    my ($obj) = @_;
    if( not defined ( $obj->{ someProp } ) ) {
        die "someProp is undefined in $obj";
    }
}
```

The function prints out the following message: "someProp is undefined in SomePackage:SomeClass=HASH(0x12345678)".
The so called class "SomePackage:SomeClass" has the property "someProp", but the property inside the passsed instance seems to have no value. But the documentation of the surrounding system says there is one.

I am no Perl developer, but maybe you can point me into a specific direction or maybe provide some debugging techniques?

Comment: `$obj->{someProp} = undef` would trigger the behavior you describe.  But the real way forward is to examine the calling code, and/or extend the debugging message to show us the value of the ostensibly missing property.

Comment: Perhaps what is sought is `if (exists $obj->{someProp})` which checks that the [key exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html), not whether its value is defined.

Comment: Data::Dumper can be helpful in outputting a full representation of the object for debugging.

Comment: Accessing a key from within an object directly is a little dirty isn't it? Is there no accessor method?

Comment: The Dumper called on $obj prints out: `$VAR1 = bless( { '_irssi' => 1234567, } ,'Irssi::Irc::Client' ) ;`

Comment: To be more specific, I'll add the original code which is separated into two parts: binding and function definition. **Binding**: `Irssi::signal_add("proxy client connected", "on_connect");`
**Function**: `sub on_connect { my ($client) = @_; if( not defined( $client->{ server } ) ) { die "Server is undefined"; } }`
So, the "on_connect" method gets called from the surrounding system (which I do know nothing about except for a very tiny documentation).

Comment: @tripleee If the property had a value other than `undefined` (e.g. an object as desired), 'die "someProp...` would not be called, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works.  I don't see anything in your code that tells the proxy which server the client wants to use, but obviously, I'm not familiar with the system.  What happens when a client connects?

Comment: Brief googling suggests that this problem happens if you fail to set up `irssiproxy_ports` when starting up the proxy (or in its configuration file).  You can set up multiple proxy ports; the client connects to the one for the remote server they want to access.

Comment: Both `irssiproxy_ports` and `irssiproxy_password` are stored savely inside irssi's config file as described in [link](http://suryahunter.com/wiki/hunter/irssi_proxy_configuration). I have reloaded the proxy module several times and it says `-!- Irssi: Proxy: Client connected from ::ffff:127.0.0.1` as expected everytime my irc-client connects. But right after that, my script "dies" because of the missing server property. But now that that you mentioned it, it's really strange that the client should have only one property for one server..it could be connected to more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, after experimenting around a bit and reading other scripts, I found the very easy solution: I was just missing an include directive for the package of the class this object was an instance of. All that was missing was `use SomePackage;` (or in that case `use Irssi::Irc;`). After that include, `obj->{ someProp }` magically had the anticipated value other than `undefined`.
**Thanks everyone for the help, though.**